Need a help to connect ReactJs to Firestore
I've tried to connect firestore with react with this code and it shows nothing
I've tried real-time database and it works but on Firestore it won't
I'm a newbie in Firebase, If you know how to connect firestore with react.
When I execute the code it shows "Uncaught FirebaseError: "projectId" not provided in firebase.initializeApp."
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  // Your Firebase configuration
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const collectionRef = collection(db, 'Name');
      const snapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);

      if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log("No data available");
      } else {
        const firstDoc = snapshot.docs[0];
        setData(firstDoc.data());
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleAddData = async (newData) => {
    try {
      const collectionRef = collection(db, 'Name');
      const docRef = await addDoc(collectionRef, newData);
      console.log("Data added successfully with ID:", docRef.id);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding data:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data ? (
        <div>
          <h2>Your Data</h2>
          <p>Key: {data.key}</p>
          <p>Value: {data.value}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading data...</p>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => handleAddData({ newKey: "newValue" })}>Add New Data</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Do you have an actual configuration for your Firebase app from Firebase Developer Console? The configuration data that you need to put on line 6 that contains text-comment // Your Firebase configuration?

Yes I've checked all the configuration and it contain no error

I guess you need to be authenticated to the Auth Service of Firebase in order to make some actions on Firestore
